# Running Python script as systemd service, connecting to InfluxDB results in ConnectionError

Tags: python, systemd, influxdb, influxdb-python, system-services

I am running a shell script as Ubuntu's systemd service to start at boot-time. The script internally executes a Python script (*python_simulator.py*) that connects to InfluxDB (through Python's influxdb package).

The Python script fails to start at boot-time and checking the logs suggests that's because of '*ConnectionError*' while connecting to InfluxDB. I interpreted it as it's possible that the influxdb service as not started by the time the Python service activates at boot time. So I have tried to add the order dependency in the service by adding "**After**" and "**Wants**" as "**influxdb.service**" which activates the Python service a few seconds after influxdb service.  But, I still get the same connection error.

The systemd service (**myservice.service)** looks like:

```
[Unit]
Description= Python startup service.
After=influxdb.service
Wants=influxdb.service

[Service]
Type=forking
ExecStart=/bin/bash /home/test_user/Deploy/start.sh
ExecStop=/bin/bash /home/test_user/Deploy/stop.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

The log file of the Python script (**python_simulator.py)**:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/test_user/Deploy/py_venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 159, in _new_conn
    (self._dns_host, self.port), self.timeout, **extra_kw)
  File "/home/test_user/Deploy/py_venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 80, in create_connection
    raise err
  File "/home/test_user/Deploy/py_venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 70, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/test_user/Deploy/py_venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 600, in urlopen
    chunked=chunked)
  File "/home/test_user/Deploy/py_venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 354, in _make_request
    conn.request(method, url, **httplib_request_kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1239, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1285, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1234, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1026, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 964, in send
    self.connect()
  File "/home/test_user/Deploy/py_venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 181, in connect
    conn = self._new_conn()
  File "/home/test_user/Deploy/py_venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 168, in _new_conn
    self, "Failed to establish a new connection: %s" % e)
urllib3.exceptions.NewConnectionError: <urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f817d91b400>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/test_user/Deploy/py_venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 449, in send
    timeout=timeout
  File "/home/test_user/Deploy/py_venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 638, in urlopen
    _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "/home/test_user/Deploy/py_venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 399, in increment
    raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=8086): Max retries exceeded with url: /query?q=SHOW+DATABASES (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f817d91b400>: Failed to establish a new connection: [$

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python_simulator.py", line 467, in <module>
    main(host=args.host, port=args.port)
  File "python_simulator.py", line 312, in main
    for db_dict in client.get_list_database():
  File "/home/test_user/Deploy/py_venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/influxdb/client.py", line 570, in get_list_database
    return list(self.query("SHOW DATABASES").get_points())
  File "/home/test_user/Deploy/py_venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/influxdb/client.py", line 416, in query
    expected_response_code=expected_response_code
  File "/home/test_user/Deploy/py_venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/influxdb/client.py", line 267, in request
    timeout=self._timeout
  File "/home/test_user/Deploy/py_venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 533, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/home/test_user/Deploy/py_venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 646, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/home/test_user/Deploy/py_venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 516, in send
    raise ConnectionError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=8086): Max retries exceeded with url: /query?q=SHOW+DATABASES (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f817d91b400>: Failed to establish a new connection$
```

Lastly, blocking tree of daemons shows that *myservice.service* executes after *influxdb.service*:

> ```
> myservice.service +6.872s
> └─influxdb.service @11.344s
>   └─network-online.target @11.337s
>     └─NetworkManager-wait-online.service @4.706s +6.630s
>       └─NetworkManager.service @3.940s +674ms
>         └─dbus.service @3.914s
>           └─basic.target @3.728s
>             └─sockets.target @3.728s
>               └─snapd.socket @3.722s +5ms
>                 └─sysinit.target @3.712s
>                   └─apparmor.service @3.276s +435ms
>                     └─local-fs.target @3.266s
>                       └─run-user-1000.mount @49.841s
>                         └─swap.target @3.160s
>                           └─dev-disk-by\x2duuid-16e1b46a\x2d79fc\x2d4965\x2d9932\x2d8f589e9e7057.swap @3.132s +23ms
>                             └─dev-disk-by\x2duuid-16e1b46a\x2d79fc\x2d4965\x2d9932\x2d8f589e9e7057.device @3.130s
> ```

I am not sure why I am still not able to execute the script (python_simulator.py) with influxdb in place. Are there any other dependencies? Are any changes needed in *myservice.service*? Any help will be appreciated.

**Edit 1:**

Can the reason be *ConnectionRefusedError* instead of *ConnectionError* and that may be because by the time it connects to influx at **Port 8086**, nothing is listening on it? If so, how can I put that in dependency order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may still run into a problem even if you create the service dependency (because it's possible that influxdb takes a moment before it is ready to accept connections, during which time the Python code might start). The solution is to either:

- write your Python code to retry connections when they are refused or
- configure systemd to restart your service if it fails.

Without seeing your Python code it's hard to suggest what the first solution might look like, but configuring your unit to restart on failure is as simple as adding the following to your `[Service]` section:

```
Restart=on-failure
```

---

You can delay startup of your Python code until influxdb is ready by adding a small shell script to your systemd unit:

```
ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c 'while ! curl -sf http://localhost:8086/ping; do sleep 1; done'
```

This will loop indefinitely (thus preventing the service from starting) until influxdb is responding successfully to the `/ping` endpoint.

Comment: The shell script that runs as a systemd service executes Python script and few other things too. Its status is always **active (running)** even if the python script has failed. Is it possible to have systemd service wait until port 8086 comes up?

Comment: I've added one possible solution to the answer, although I think either of the previous two suggestions would be better (because what happens if you have to restart the influxdb service after your Python code is already running?)

Comment: I agree that configuring systemd to restart on failure is a better solution. But as I said error in executing .py doesn't lead to failing .sh service and thus it won't restart.

Comment: Though, the solution to wait for the port 8086 has worked just fine. To check what happens if influxdb stops, it actually stopped myservice as well. I am assuming it's because I had **Wants** as influxdb.service under myservice.service. Though, I expect it to restart as I had put "Restart=on-failure" (May be because, its' dead and it didn't fail)

Comment: Thanks for this. However (I haven't investigated 'deeply') this wouldn't work for me until I added `TimeoutSec=360` into the unit as well as the ping. See also:  https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/227017/how-to-change-systemd-service-timeout-value